# Isomorphic lists

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, rule

Is there a function that outputs `True` if lists are isomorphic (there exists a rule that changes the first list into the second one and inverse of the rule changes the second list into the first one) and `False` otherwise?

If there is no such function implemented in Mathematica, can you provide a shorter code than mine?

I was also considering that `IsomorphicGraphQ` can be somehow used to do the job but I did not find anything.

```
a = {1, 2, 2, 3};
b = {3, 7, 7, 8};
c = {3, 7, 7, 3};
d = {5, 3, 3, 1};
And @@ DuplicateFreeQ /@ (Transpose[#] // Union // Transpose) &@{a, b}
And @@ DuplicateFreeQ /@ (Transpose[#] // Union // Transpose) &@{b, c}
And @@ DuplicateFreeQ /@ (Transpose[#] // Union // Transpose) &@{a, d}
And @@ DuplicateFreeQ /@ (Transpose[#] // Union // Transpose) &@{a, b, d}
And @@ DuplicateFreeQ /@ (Transpose[#] // Union // Transpose) &@{a, b, c}
```

---

```
True

False

True

True

False
```

Comment: Does the order of elements matter?

Comment: Yes, the order matters.

Answer (score 6):

Not fully tested, but works for your examples:

```
SameStructureQ[a_, b_] := a == (b /. Reverse[DeleteDuplicatesBy[Thread[a -> b], First], 2])
```

You'd need to generalize if you want to do more than pairwise testing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another strategy based on "normalizing" a list by structure.

```
SameStructureQ[a_, b_] := Values[PositionIndex[a]] == Values[PositionIndex[b]]
```

This assumes that PositionIndex always works in the same deterministic order.

Answer (score 5):

A variation of lericr's first answer

```
f = #1 == (#2 /. AssociationMap[Reverse] @ AssociationThread[#1 -> #2]) &
```

**Cases 1 - 3**

```
f @@@ {{a, b}, {b, c}, {a, d}}
```

> {True, False, True}

**Cases 4 - 5**

```
f[a, b] && f[a, d]
```

> True

```
f[a, b] && f[a, c]
```

> False

**Revision 1**

Let it work with more than 2 lists

```
IsomorphicQ[a_, b_] := 
 Equal[a, b /. AssociationMap[Reverse] @ AssociationThread[a -> b]]

IsomorphicQ[a_, b__] := 
 And @@ Map[IsomorphicQ[a, #] &, {b}]
```

```
IsomorphicQ @@@ {{a, b}, {b, c}, {a, d}, {a, b, d}, {a, b, c}}
```

> {True, False, True, True, False}

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {1, 2, 2, 3};
b = {3, 7, 7, 8};
c = {3, 7, 7, 3};
d = {5, 3, 3, 1};
```

Using `Counts`

```
IsomorphicQ[x__] := Equal @@ Values @* Counts /@ {x}
```

```
IsomorphicQ[b, c]
```

> False

```
IsomorphicQ[a, b, d]
```

> True

```
IsomorphicQ @@@ {{a, b}, {b, c}, {a, d}, {a, b, d}, {a, b, c}}
```

> {True, False, True, True, False}

Answer (score 2):

```
isoQ = Apply[SameQ] @* Map[ArrayComponents];

{a, b, c, d} = {{1, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 7, 7, 8}, {3, 7, 7, 3}, {5, 3, 3, 1}};

isoQ /@ {{a, b}, {b, c}, {a, d}, {a, b, d}, {a, b, c}}
```

> ```
> {True, False, True, True, False}
> ```